# Creating a javascript class with an object containing functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a javascript "class" and it is working somewhat good, but the Engine.tile.draw isn't working as intended. I cannot seem to get it to work inside Engine.start. Is it not possible to create an object and add a function inside it, like I did? How would you guys do it? Any help is appreciated. :)

```
var EngineClass = ( function () {
    var Engine = function () {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById('game');
        this.handle = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    };

    Engine.prototype.start = function (mapData) {
        this.tile.draw(mapData);
    };

    Engine.prototype.tile = {
      draw: function (x, y, tile) {
        this.handle.fillText(tile, x * 16, y * 16);
      };
    }

    return Engine;
})();

var Engine = new EngineClass();
```

Comment: Javascript is a PROTOTYPE based object orientated language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), not a class based object orientated language. Just don't do it that way. You wouldn't build a lawn mower engine into your car, so don't build classes in JS.

Comment: there are no classes in javascript

Comment: That's why I said "class". I know there isn't any classes in the current version av ECMA, but that is a common way to emulate it. But the part where I try to add functions inside an object (Engine.tile) isn't common, I guess, since it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really  work to use sub -bjects like you are here:

```
Engine.prototype.tile = {
  draw: function (x, y, tile) {
    this.handle.fillText(tile, x * 16, y * 16);
  };
}
```

The issue is that when you call `Engine.tile.draw()`, the `this` pointer inside the `draw()` method will be set to the `tile` object which is not what your code is assuming (your code assumes that `this` points to the `Engine` instance which is not what happens).

If you really want a sub-object like this, then you will need to intialize that sub-object in the Engine constructor so that each `tile` object is set up uniquely and then you will need to add its engine pointer to the `tile` instance data so that when `Engine.tile.draw()` is called, you can get the appropriate `Engine` instance from the `this` pointer that points to the `tile` object.  But, this is all a mess and probably both unnecessary and the hard way of doing things.

You should probably either make `tile` its own object with its own instance data or put the draw method on the Engine object and just pass it some arguments that help it do its job.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, thanks. So basically, your recommendation is to make 'tile' its own object? Tile will contain A LOT more later, so I guess that is a good idea then.

Comment: @Jan - if `tile` will have a lot of operations and data of its own, then yes you should make it its own object.  If, in order to `draw()` itself, it needs to know the `handle` that it should use for drawing, then perhaps that should be stored in the `tile` instance data so it can carry out the `draw()` method on its own.  Or alternatively, you could have each `tile` have a reference to its parent `Engine` and you could get the `handle` from there.  The point is that when methods are called on the `tile` object, the `this` pointer will be the `tile` object.

Answer (score 0):

The comments above saying you shouldn't try to force classes on JavaScript which is a prototypical language are correct.

Technically, the reason this doesn't work is that whenever you invoke a function using dot notation (e.g. `something.method()`), the function gets invoked with `this` bound to the left hand side of the dot. So in this case, when you say `this.tile.draw(mapData)`, the `tile.draw` function gets invoked with `this` being the `tile` object, rather than the `Engine` object as you'd expect.

There are several ways to overcome this but the best advice is to shift your mindset to JavaScript's prototyping system instead of trying to force your class-based mindset on it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` inside `draw` function will refer to the `Engine.prototype.tile` object, not what you expected.

Change

```
Engine.prototype.tile = {
  draw: function (x, y, tile) {
    this.handle.fillText(tile, x * 16, y * 16);
  };
}
```

to

```
Engine.prototype.tile = function() {
  var self = this;
  return {
    draw: function (x, y, tile) {
      self.handle.fillText(tile, x * 16, y * 16);
    };
  };
}
```

And call it like:

```
Engine.prototype.start = function (mapData) {
    this.tile().draw(mapData);
};
```